# Angular: Blank page after $scope variable change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I have an angular app which routes to a template called viewAll.html after a link is clicked.

This page has some data which is populated via AJAX through scope variables.

The problem is that whenever I make an update to these scope variables via AJAX and try to render it, the page becomes blank. The template doesn't load back.

Here is the code:

```
$http({
    method: 'post',
    url: appContext('MarkMessageAsReadV2.json'),
    data: {
        "customerNotificationId":"", 
        "isRead":"Y", 
        "channelTypeCode":"101", 
        "readAll":"Y", 
        "customerType": "A"
    }
}).success(function (data) {
    $http.post(appContext('ViewAllNotificationsV2.json'), {
            "categoryGroupType":"ROLB",
            "isArchived":"N",
            "channelTypeCode":"101",
            "limit":"20",
            "page":"0",
            "customerType": "A"
        }).success(function(content, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.notifications = content.all.notification;
            $scope.personalNotifications = content.personal.notification;
            $scope.businessNotifications = content.business.notification;
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            // log error
        });
}).error(function (a, b, c) {
        console.log(a, b, c);
});
```

Comment: What you see in the console ? 
Is there any error ?

Comment: Can you check if that variable try to load your html template or partial outside the controller scope. I have seen in few cases if you render an html outside the scope from a controller it mess up the scope and gives you blank screen

Comment: Is there a reason you're chaining your promises like that?.  I noticed that `$http.post( /* get notifications */)` is not dependent on the previous promise's data return.

Answer (score 0):

try to use **$scope.apply()** after scope variables

```
$scope.notifications = content.all.notification;
$scope.personalNotifications = content.personal.notification;
$scope.businessNotifications = content.business.notification;
$scope.$apply();
```

Comment: $http promise chain is executed during digest, there's no place for $apply or $digest.